# sql server cross join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select 
    tt.ItemOrder, tt.DisplayVal as Task, tt.Responsible as ResParty, 
    tt.DaysDue,  
    ActualDate = (select convert(varchar(10), cnfmdate, 101) from ProSer where PId = @PID), PDate = @PDate 
from 
    tblTimeline tt
where
    tt.ID = 1
```

What I need to do is to put it in a view such that I can call the view simply using the PID.
I came up with the following and used the cross join:

```
create view view1 as
    select 
        ps.PID, tt.ID, tt.ItemOrder, tt.DisplayVal as Task, 
        tt.Responsible as ResParty, tt.DaysDue,  
        ps.cnfmdate As ActualDate, ProgStartDate as ProgramDate  
    from 
        tblTimeline tt 
   cross join 
        ProSer ps
   where 
        tt.ID = 1 and ps.cancelled = 0
```

Notice now, I can do the following

```
select * 
from view1 
where PID = '34343'
```

and then I can retrieve it from the view.

Now, I am not sure how to do similiarly with the following in which case I need to put it in a cross join similarly to how I did above.

Notice how actual date is somehat more involved. I need to use the cross table similarly to how I did it above but not as you can see, it is somewhat more involved.

(notice for this part, I will simly join to the view1 that I have above with UNION

```
select 
    tt.ItemOrder, tt.DisplayVal as Task, tt.Responsible as ResParty, 
    ActualDate = (
          CASE
          WHEN
             NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Spls WHERE RequestRcvd = 1 AND PID = @PID)
          THEN 
             'N/A'       
          WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM spls WHERE RequestRcvd = 1 AND RequestRcvdDate IS NOT NULL)
          THEN
             (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(RequestRcvdDate),101) from spls WHERE RequestRcvd = 1 AND PID = @PID)   
          END
          )   
from 
    tblTimeline tt
where 
    tt.ID = 9
```

I need to know how I can create this in a cross join (which will be inside of a view) such that I can do the following similarly to how I did the above one

```
select * 
from view1 
where PID = '34343'
```

and then I can retrieve it from the view.

Comment: Does proser contain the PID that you want in the query?

Comment: Yes proser does contain the PID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to simplify the query, but the following should work:

```
select p.pid, tt.ItemOrder, tt.DisplayVal as Task,
       tt.Responsible as ResParty,
       ActualDate = (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Spls WHERE RequestRcvd = 1 AND spls.PID = p.PID) 
                          THEN 'N/A'
                          WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM spls WHERE RequestRcvd = 1 AND RequestRcvdDate IS NOT NULL)
                          THEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(RequestRcvdDate),101) from spls WHERE RequestRcvd = 1 AND spls.PID = p.PID)
                     END)
from tblTimeline tt cross join
     poser p
where tt.ID = 9
```

All I did was add the cross join to poser and replace @PID with p.pid.  The results is a subquery that contains a reference to a table at an outer level.  Such a subquery is called a correlated subquery.